# NeedIndexError at Google App Engine forever

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I deployed and ran my app at GAE a few hours ago. It still fails because it needs to order certain datastore item, and the index needed for that is still not generated by GAE. So at the point of `.order()` it throws me a **NeedIndexError**. How long is this gonna take?

I've been doing this same procedure for 10~ GAE apps in the past and it has never, to my memory, been this slow. (Ok, it has been slow...)

- The page "Datastore Indexes" in the old console just says "You have not created indexes for this application.".
- The new console says nothing. It just displays a "blue alert" as if I'm not waiting myself to death already. The message in the alert is:

> Cloud Datastore queries are powered by indexes, scalable data
>   structures that are updated in real time as property values change.
>   Your project's datastore index configuration specifies the indexes it
>   needs to support its queries. Cloud Datastore builds new indexes as
>   needed when you deploy index configuration. You can inspect the ready
>   state of your app's indexes using this console.

(ie a joke)

What am I supposed to do?

Update:

here's the index.yaml:

```
indexes:

# AUTOGENERATED

- kind: Mjquizinfo
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: version
    direction: desc
```

Comment: What i do is i create a cursor query for the entities i need a new index for which loads and saves each entity thus creating the indexes for the existing entities. If you index is a composite index you should check if that index is deployed in the correct index configuration file.

Comment: I just deploy the index.yaml generated locally as is. It shuold be pretty simple. I pasted it in my question.

Comment: As far as i know when you define a new index only new entities will have their properties indexed. Old entities are unaffected. But the error shouldn't look like that. Is the order in which you sort in your code the same as the defined index (asc vs. desc)?

Comment: Yes it's the same. This is another app B for a new project, but the exact same code as app A that is already running since 6+ months. The order is the same (- for desc). Three hours and still no response what so ever. I have to give up for today. It will just magically work tomorrow...

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time that a good night's sleep solves a problem with app engine :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, in some cases (multi-module apps for example) the plain `appcfg.py update` used to deploy the app code **might not** update the `index.yaml` file.

Try [specifically updating the index](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp?hl=en#Python_Updating_indexes) using `appcfg.py update_indexes` - you should be able to see the index info in the Developer Console right away (it may still take a while for indexing to be performed and become effective).

Comment: 12 hours later and still no go, and this seems to work well - said index is now at least visible, in "preparing". 2+ years with GAE and I have never had to do that before. Thanks. FWIW, I don't use appcfg.py to deploy anymore, I normally deploy from a git repository. Something with the workflow there might have changed concerning the indexes.

Comment: And there it went into "serving" just a few seconds later. You made my day.

Comment: takes a while if you have lots of data. maybe your previous projects didn't.